# datagridview pans on clicking a cell

Tags: c#, winforms, .net-4.0

I have a winforms application that has a datagridview control. Now, when I click on a cell in the datagridview control, the view shifts/pans the datagridview control, such that the cell selected is more or less in the centre of the screen. Is there any way to disable this? My users find this irritating.

The data gridview is essentially needed only to show colour codes (i.e. no text) and tooltips for each cell. I have tried

```
datagridView1.Enabled = false;
```

This solves my problem, however, I can no longer view the tooltip text.
Is there any other work-around? Is it possible to prevent the user from clicking on a cell in the first place to prevent this?

Comment: You could just catch the cell click event and not let them focus on the cell or select what is in it...?